# keras - model wont work after pop()

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have taken a standard ResNet50 model:

```
model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                                     weights='imagenet',
                                     classes=10,
                                     input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
```

And added several dense layers of my own:

```
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model = Model(input=model.input, output=top_model(model.output))
```

This way it works great, however, when I want to delete last Dense and Dropout layers with `model.pop()` keras wont work well:

```
model.layers[-1].layers
[<keras.layers.core.Flatten at 0x16b5c00b8>,
 <keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x16b5c0320>,
 <keras.layers.core.Dropout at 0x16b5c02e8>,
 <keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x16b5c0d68>]

model.layers[-1].pop()
model.layers[-1].pop()
model.layers[-1].layers

[<keras.layers.core.Flatten at 0x1ae6e5940>,
 <keras.layers.core.Dense at 0x1ae6e9e10>]

model.layers[-1].outputs = [model.layers[-1].layers[-1].output]
model.outputs = model.layers[-1].outputs
model.layers[-1].layers[-1].outbound_nodes = []
```

Then I just compile the model and when trying to predict, I get an error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'flatten_7_input_12' with dtype float and shape [?,1,1,2048]
```

Answer (score 0):

`model.pop()` takes care of all the underlying settings, including setting the `model.output` to the output of the new last layer. Therefore, you don't need to handle anything regarding the outputs.
Please also note that you are assigning to the `model` variable; thus, `model.outputs` is already referring to the extended model's output.

Here is a sample code that works fine on keras 2.0.6 with TensorFlow backend (1.4.0):

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

model = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                                 weights='imagenet',
                                 classes=10,
                                 input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model_extended = Model(input=model.input, output=top_model(model.output))
model_extended.layers[-1].pop()
model_extended.layers[-1].pop()
model_extended.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_extended.predict(np.zeros((1, 224, 224, 3)))
```

Comment: My last layer is a model itself. If I call `model.pop` I will pop both Dense layers, Dropout and Flatten. I only want to pop the last Dense and Dropout.

Please read the question before answering it

Comment: I understand that your last layer is itself a sequential model. However, setting the outputs manually is not necessary if you use model.pop() on a sequential model. Check my extended answer.